# Configure gitlab ci so it only deploys configuration file if no other code changes were made?

Tags: deployment, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Currently our deployments are being done automatically when a commit is done to the master branch via gitlab ci.  We deploy two things, a war and a configuration file for each repo, the config file is in the same repo as the code that builds the war.

I'd like to change this logic so that if I make a commit that only changes the configuration file then only the configuration file will be deployed, ie don't re-deploy a war if the code for the war hasn't been modified.

Is there a clean way to update our gliab-ci so it can determine rather to deploy war, config file, or both based off of files changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Clean but manual way

Ask your developer to add a special flag into the commit message, for example `[DEPLY_CFG]`. Then inside your `.gitlab-ci.yml`, make the particular job to have this `only` attribute:

```
only:
  variables:
    - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[DEPLY_CFG\]/
```

## Auto but not-so-clean way

Add the following command to check if the particular file was in the committed file list:

```
CFG_MOD=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r ${CI_COMMIT_SHA} | grep path/to/the/config/file)
```

Then, simply use `if [[ -n "${CFG_MOD}" ]]` to decide whether to deploy the config file or not.

N.B: By 'clean' for the manual way, I mean the deployment decision is visible from the pipelines screen based on the name of jobs, whereas with the not-so-clean automatic way you cannot determine which deployment decision from the pipelines screen because the conditional clause is embedded inside a single job.